# How does a light source / laser transfer energy to a material?

Tags: thermodynamics, particle-physics, laser, heat-conduction, laser-interaction

I am trying to understand the physics of how a laser is able to heat a solid. My understanding so far is that when photons are incident upon a body (e.g. a metal) the momentum of the photons is transferred to the particles (free electrons, atoms, molecules etc) raising the kinetic energy of the body. What I am struggling to factor into this is the dependence on wavelength.

I suspect this is due to inelastic collisions, but what enables these collisions to exist if the photon energies don't directly correspond to the energy states of the electrons of the atoms that form the solid. Supposedly this is the mechanism that makes glass transparent - the photon energies are misaligned and therefore don't interact with the electrons of the atoms and pass straight through - but then how does something like graphite block a broadband of light while only consisting of carbon?

Answer (score 2):

Many materials have so many available energy states that they effectively form a continuum of states. These materials can absorb any wavelength that corresponds to the difference in energy between an occupied state and a higher-energy unoccupied state.

> My understanding so far is that when photons are incident upon a body ... the momentum of the photons is transferred to the particles (free electrons, atoms, molecules etc) raising the kinetic energy of the body.

You really should consider energy first and momentum second. The absorption of an electron transfers energy to the absorbing material. That form the energy takes after absorption might be kinetic, but it could also be electrostatic (when an electron is promoted to a higher "orbital" around the nucleus), vibrational, etc.

Typically the momentum of the photon is too low to affect the net momentum of even a tiny massive particle like an electron. However the mismatch between the photon momentum and the momentum associated with the available electronic states can affect the allowed transition processes, for example it relates to why silicon is a poor light emitter.

Comment: "Many materials have so many available energy states that they effectively form a continuum of states. These materials can absorb any wavelength that corresponds to the difference in energy between an occupied state and a higher-energy unoccupied state."

I specifically mentioned graphite as it only consists of carbon yet will produce heat when a laser of a non specific wavelength is cast upon it. I don't think the mechanism for heating involves exciting electrons between orbitals. I'm not sure what else to think other than through the transfer of momentum.